# Rails RESTful API + Devise - How to check for user's credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, restful-architecture

I've built a RESTful API with Ruby On Rails, and now I good like to know whether the user's credentials received by POST are valid or not, using Devise.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devise - [getting started](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started) should set you up.

EDIT:

Devise, by default, validates users by their email and password. If you want to add validation by username, refer [this wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)
Basically, you need to add username to the model and make it 'attr-accessible'

Devise sets up paths for user sign-up, sign-in and sign-out, etc.
Refer [devise asciicast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise) for these path helpers.

To write controller tests, refer to [this wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29) for details.

EDIT:

Sorry for not understanding your requirements. Here is [how to find user from credentials](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Find-a-user-when-you-have-their-credentials). This you can use from your service to validate user.

Comment: I cannot find a method to pass username and password and let me sign in a user. That's what I need to provide: username AND password, both of them.

Comment: I'm not sure I was clear enough on what I want to do. I've got a REST service, which will receive username and password fields. Then, with Devise, I will have to check if those credentials belong to a registered user. Do any of your links solve this issue?

Comment: Edited my response according to your requirements. HTH.